# simple higher order functions in scheme

Tags: function, scheme

I'm trying to understand how to pass functions as arguments in scheme but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding tutorials.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
(define (addone n)
(+ n 1))
(define (for-n start stop fn)
(if (< start stop)
    (list)
    (cons (fn start) (for-n (+ start 1) stop fn))))
```

Basically I just want a function that returns the values of fn for start, start+1, ... start+stop in a list.

Expected output of (for-n 1 5 (addone 0)) would thus be (1 2 3 4 5).
I think I'm really missing some very basic concepts here because I don't seem to even be calling the function in the interpreter correctly and I'm not grasping how to tell scheme to interpret fn as a function rather than just a regular parameter.

I figured it out (though through sheer trial and error) and I'm not sure what I did but at least it works!

```
 (define (function x)
    x)
(define (for-n start stop fn)
  (if (> start stop)
    (list)
    (cons (fn start) (for-n (+ start 1) stop fn)))))
```

Comment: Do you have a problem of just asking questions and leaving them undiscussed ..... The respondents put their valuable time to answer your question and leaving them like this , undiscussed or unaccepted...... is it justified ?

Answer (score 1):

The function invocation `(addone 0)` is equal to the value `1`. If you want to pass the function `addone` itself (as opposed to `1`), don't wrap it in parentheses at all. `(for-n 1 5 addone)` passes the `addone` function to `for-n`. If you wrap parentheses around it, Scheme will call `addone` and pass the result.

Answer (score 1):

Some feedback, for you to know what was wrong with your first version:

- The base case for a recursion that builds a list usually usually returns `'()` and not `(list)`
- As you've already discovered, the condition for the base case was wrong: the recursion ends when `(> start stop)` and not when `(< start stop)` as initially stated
- It's not necessary to define an `addone` procedure, at least in some Scheme interpreters there already exists a procedure called `add1`
- Finally, when invoking a procedure that receives another procedure, just pass along the function, no need to apply it first - that will return a *value* and not a function as intended. What I mean to say is that this is wrong: `(for-n 1 5 (addone 0))` and this is correct: `(for-n 1 5 addone)`. When you write `(addone 0)` the function gets applied and returns the value `1`, and what you intended to pass was `addone`, the procedure itself.

With all the above suggestions in place, this is how a correct procedure should look:

```
(define (for-n start stop fn)
  (if (> start stop)
      '()
      (cons (fn start) (for-n (add1 start) stop fn))))
```

Call it like this:

```
(for-n 1 5 add1)
> '(2 3 4 5 6)
```